# Change Drag Style On NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I try to change the style from the blue horizontal line to Drop On style but found no luck. Does anybody knows why. I searched for a morning and do everything but still not luck replace that horizontal line with the row highlight focus on the row being dropped on.

```
- (NSDragOperation)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView validateDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info proposedItem:(id)targetItem proposedChildIndex:(NSInteger)index{

BOOL canDrop = index >= 0 && targetItem;

if (canDrop) {
    [outlineView setDropRow:index dropOperation:NSOutlineViewDropOnItemIndex];
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
} else {
    return NSDragOperationNone;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It actually pretty simple after a little more of trying. For anyone who are not able to replace the blue horizontal line on drop by row highlight in NSOutlineView. Add this delegate to NSOutlineView Delegate methods:

```
- (NSDragOperation)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView validateDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info proposedItem:(id)targetItem proposedChildIndex:(NSInteger)index{

BOOL canDrag = index >= 0 && targetItem;

if (canDrag) {
    [outlineView setDropItem:[outlineView itemAtRow:index] dropChildIndex:NSOutlineViewDropOnItemIndex];
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
} else {
    return NSDragOperationNone;
}
```

}